# Correct way to convert string to unsigned number in C++

Tags: c++

I tried to use:

```
std::string s = "-150";
unsigned int a = atoi(s.c_str());
std::cout << a;
```

and

```
std::string s = "-150";
std::istringstream reader(s);
unsigned int a;
reader >> a;
std::cout << a;
```

I always get `4294967146`. I understand that it's a `U_INT_MAX - 150`.
How can I get an error if number can't be converted, cause input data was invalid?
Or (at least) auto-convert to `150`. 
P.S. 
I want to find a way without my manipulation on string.

Comment: There's the [`abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) function, I think that's what you're looking for actually.

Comment: The input data is valid, at least as far as `atoi` is concerned.

Comment: If you use the `std::stoi` family of functions it will raise an exception if there is an invalid conversion.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks.

Comment: @NathanOliver No: "If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value calculated from the sequence of digits is negated as if by unary minus in the result type, which applies unsigned integer wraparound rules." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul

Answer (score 3):

You expect a **number** as input and want to check it fits in `unsigned int`, then do it so. Convert the string to an universal data type for numbers (signed, floating point, much room -> **double**) and check if it can be casted without precision lost to your wished type.

You want an integer with no sign, so your number has to be positive, is in given range (so far see [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)) and has no decimal part.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that even `std::stoul` doesn't reject negative numbers (presumably due to the requirements of `strtoul`, which it uses).  Here's a test program to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout, etc.
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stoul
#include <stdexcept>  // std::invalid_argument, std::out_of_range
#include <limits>     // std::numeric_limits

int main(int, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv) {
        std::string str(*argv);
        try {
            unsigned long u = std::stoul(str);
            if (u > std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())
                throw std::out_of_range(str);

            unsigned int i = u;
            std::cout << "Value = " << i << std::endl;
        } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
            std::cout << "Input could not be parsed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
            std::cout << "Input out of range: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Running this with arguments `150 -150 abc` gives

```
Value = 150
Input out of range: -150
Input could not be parsed: stoul
```

But, if we remove the `std::numeric_limits` test, we get

```
Value = 150
Value = 4294967146
Input could not be parsed: stoul
```

---

### TL;DR

Read as an `unsigned long` and test the range yourself (wrap it up in a function - perhaps even a template function - if you find you need it in many places).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get an error if number can't be casted, cause input data was invalid?

You can read into a `signed int` variable in 1st place:

```
unsigned int a = 0;
int a_input = atoi(s.c_str());
if(a_input < 0) {
    std::err << "Invalid input." << std::endl;
}
else {
    a = a_input;
}
```

If you need to cover the full range of `unsigned int` input, choose the next bigger data type available:

```
long a_input = atol(s.c_str());
```

> Or (at least) auto-convert to `150`.

That's not a matter of casting. You should simply use the [`std::abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) function to achieve what you want:

```
unsigned int a = std::abs(atoi(s.c_str()));
              // ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How does this _"get an error if number can't be casted, cause input data was invalid?"_

Comment: Then it doesn't answer the question!

Comment: `atoi` (or `atol`) is a poor choice of function if `0` might be a valid input, distinct from the error case.

Comment: @TobySpeight Feel free to give a better answer, I'm aware that's not ideal. Though the question isn't very precise about the actual requirements.