# In C++, how do I pass a 32 bit number into an 'int' variable without anything above 0x7FFFFFFF being considered negative?

Tags: c++

I need to have an `int` variable go up to 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF), without using `unsigned` and `long`, so it can actually be used by other functions. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, if you can find or create a compiler that support that.

Comment: It is possible only if your platform has an `int` larger than 32 bit. If your platform has 32 bit `int` then it cannot represent `4294967295`. Why are you trying to avoid `unsigned`? It would fix your problem.

Comment: Dirty but widely used hack: `#define int long long` ... Oops, this uses `long`. Then `#define int int64_t`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why you can't use `unsigned int`? What does 'used by other functions' mean?

Comment: @MikeCAT: Alas the behaviour of doing that is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, unless you find a platform with an `int` that's larger than 32 bits (they are at the time of writing rare).

If you need to use a `signed` type, then `std::int64_t` is a good choice. Or `long long` is also guaranteed to be large enough.

---

If you're *absolutely* constrained by the interface to your function then you could break your number up into two parts - and adopt the convention that you need to call the function twice to get anything meaningful out of it. But that could make your program very brittle.

---

Another option: if your function is allowed to take the `int` *by reference* then you could have an array of two `int`s at the call site, and pass the first one to your function. You can then reach the other using pointer arithmetic within the function body! Again, this will make your code brittle but it would work.

Comment: OK, I figured out how to use `unsigned int` in my functions. Sorry for an off-topic question, is there a way to convert a string into an unsigned int?

Comment: @MaximKhannaov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895208/correct-way-to-convert-string-to-unsigned-number-in-c

Comment: But can I convert and `int` into an `unsigned int`? How?

Comment: @MaximKhannaov: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975340/int-to-unsigned-int-conversion

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Because:
an `int` value *is defined as* 31 bits plus one leading bit as a sign.

You can push whatever you want into the 32 bits of an `int`, as long as it is *declared* as `int`, the leading bit will always be interpreted as the sign.

Comment: Be careful: not necessarily. Although from C++20, `int` has to be a 2's complement type, with a minimum range [-32768, 32767]